# Object not Augmenting on small marker

Tags: unity, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to **Augmented reality**. I am developing a jewellery try on app with vuforia using unty3D editor. 
What I want is to augment a ring on the marker. I download an image(attached bellow) and used it as my marker and it was working fine but when I resized the image in paint to fit to finger the marker stopped augmenting the object.
any help.
[image]

- What should be the marker size or anything else which I am missing ?
  Please help me.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with AR, but usually the markers are fairly simple, QR-code-like shapes that are easily recognizable at any size or angle.

Comment: @jzx The image in the post is one of Vuforia's sample markers.  Vuforia uses high-contrast high-angular images of any variety.  The stones here are a 5-star target.  Something like a ring on a finger would be a very poor target, possibly completely unrecognizable.

Answer (score 2):

This guide from Vuforia gives some advice on marker design:

[Image Target Guide](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Training/Image-Target-Guide)

Specifically the section named "Designing Target Images"

However I've had success with image markers down to approx. 2x2 cm, using custom marker graphics in good conditions.

Since marker size is critical in your situation I would also look at alternative solutions, such as simple QR markers or Vuforia's framemarkers. 
Or if identification of the unique marker is not a requirement then I'd also look at custom solutions using OpenCV or similar.

Comment: hey, thanks I will try and come back soon. thank you